# Reference class can not inherit from IAudioSessionNotification in C++

Tags: c++, windows, inheritance

I'm trying to create a service that acts like the built-in volume mixer in windows. For this I need my class to inherit from `IAudioSessionNotification` in order to get a notification anytime a new audio session is created. I've written this entire code in C++ and it works fine. Now I want to make this into a C# service, so I figured I should make my existing C++ class into a runtime component so I can include it in C#.

The problem is that for this to work I need to make my class a reference class, which means that I can not inherit from `IAudioSessionNotification`, because `a C++/CX mapping ref class can only derive from another ref class or from interface classes`. Is there any way to still inherit from IAudioSessionNotification, or have my class not be a reference class?

```cpp
public ref class AudioInterfaces : public IAudioSessionNotification sealed {
public:
  AudioInterfaces();
};
```

Comment: You could create a wrapper class in c++CX, and then store a pointer to `public class AudioInterface` and re-direct all the functions through there.